# Why is echo not working for mt valgrind command?

Tags: command-line, make, debugging, c++, gnu-make

So I have my makefile working great, except that It doesn't create the valgrind.out file and I don't know why. So the console succesfully prints out that my executable file line is created but not valgrind.out

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the target:

```
make valgrind
```

as it is not part of `all`.

#### *Other notes*

In the Makefile you (very likely) have to specify the directory by `./line` as opposed to `line` under the *valgrind* target.

And as noted by [@casey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/53706/casey) use `$(EXEC)` for consistency.

Further you should likely also replace `>&` with `>file 2>&1` as the latter is more likely accepted in [what ever shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html), (likely sh), your make uses.

Thus something like:

```
valgrind:
    valgrind --leak-check=yes ./$(EXEC) >valgrind.out 2>&1
    @echo 'valgrind.out has been created'
```

Comment: It is also probably worthwhile making the `valgrind` target depend on `$(EXEC)`